# Xsl fo basic link does not create a external link in pdf properly

Tags: flexslider

Xsl fo basic link doens't work if link gets broken in two parts and also if link is in one line it doesn't work in adobe.

I tried using keep together inline feature but it doesn't work.Also i tried using hyphenate it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you add an XSL-FO sample of a link that breaks into two parts plus a closeup screenshot of it in the output? Which formatter are you using? Antenna House Formatter worked on this several years ago now, so I'd be interested to know whether the problem occurs with it.